# Stopping boost odeint integration on "steady state"

Tags: c++, boost, odeint

I am using the boost odeint library to integrate an ode. Now to save computational time I was wondering since my system should have steady state if it is possible to stop the integration when the change is below a certain threshold?

Would it be possible to implement something like that in the simplified model below?

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

/* setting namespaces */
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;
using namespace std;

/* defining constants */
const double a = 0.3;
const double tmax = 1000;

/* defining a type that will hold the 'state' arrays */ 
typedef boost::array<double ,2> state_type;

int model(const state_type &r ,state_type &drdt ,const double t){
    drdt[0] = a*r[1];
    drdt[1] = -a*r[1];
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    state_type r;
    auto stepper = make_controlled( 1.0e-5 , 1.0e-5 , runge_kutta_cash_karp54< state_type >() );
    
    /* init */
    r[0] = 0;
    r[1] = 10;

    integrate_adaptive( stepper , model , r , 0.0 , tmax , 0.01 );
    
    cout << r[0] << ";" << r[1] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As you are using `integrate_adaptive`, would imagine the timesteps are already chosen seperately from the set dt. Thus when a steady-state is found, the timesteps will be taken quite large. But I'd have to check that. And afaik you set the 'stop condition' by selecting the errors when calling `make_controlled`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used an observer function to check the size of the timesteps and you are right they are getting very large so I guess I don't have to worry about it.

Comment: I'm still checking it. Something weird happens at the end. But I'm fighting with ms excel that doesn't want to import my csv file with different decimal separator. Stupid ms...

Comment: Yeah, after about 120 timesteps (t=42) a steady state is reached... but the stepper still makes a lot of points (600 or so) until t=1000. Not sure how to limit that... I'm actively using odeint in a project now, but still don't fully understand how it works.

Comment: You are using an explicit time scheme. If your equation is stiff, they may be forced to use small time steps to remain stable, even when they are very close to the steady-state values, i.e. you may have the impression that the solver takes unnecessarily low time step values. Use an implicit integrator instead to solve this issue.your equation does not seem to be stiff. Maybe the default maximum time step allowed is too small